# Issues installing strapi

Tags: strapi, unsupportedoperation

**The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version ">=12.x.x <=16.x.x". Got "18.3.0"
error Found incompatible module.**

I'm seeing this error when I trying to do npx create-strapi-app. unsupported engine.
Has anyone seen this error and been able to figure out what to do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only LTS versions are supported (v14 and v16). Other versions of Node.js may not be compatible with the latest release of Strapi. The 14.x version is most recommended by Strapi.

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/installation/cli.html#preparing-the-installation

**Follow this article to downgrade node:**
https://dev.to/smpnjn/how-to-change-nodejs-version-34b7